# An 70s or 80s horror plotting a large serpent or dragon living under a mansion in deep hole or well or chamber and eats humans

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

Title: Something about a serpent
Approx Year: 1960s - 1980s not after 1989
Genre: Horror, Thriller, Suspense, Drama
Location: Maybe UK or US. Not many people in cast. Max 10 and cold weather with sunlight in scenes.

Reason for very wague Timeline because - India in 1990s was not very up-to-date in terms of international movie releases. Specially the VHD stores were keeping very old collection of movies out of which we had to choose.

I remember I was in my 10-16 years of age at that time. It must have been very old movie, my dad got it on a VHD on rent. Today I am 33yrs old in 2017. I saw it while I was in 8th standard or close. That was approximately 20 yrs ago from today.

I only remember glimpses of that movie now but I will try to give as many clues as I can-

Plot Description -
The frame of the movie was mostly not bright sunny but it wasn't dark either.
The mansion was big. Had a care taker or two, I don't remember.

1. The movie had a large serpent / snake / dragon perhaps with a weird face.
2. The serpent used to live under the basement / well / chamber of a hotel or a guest house.
3. A bunch of youngsters, 3 lady / 3 men come to stay there.
4. The caretaker of that place also used to ensure the creature finds its prey
5. I am not sure but possibly the ladies were likely taken by that snake before the men.
6. I don't know if it was killed in the end or a couple of them were able to escape.

That memory is very very dim now.
Can anyone tell me the name of this movie ?
Or any hints on how can I get to it ?

Comment: Long shot, but the only thing which comes to mind is The Lair of the White Worm (1988). See [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095488/) / [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lair_of_the_White_Worm_(film)).

Comment: @Bobulous, you should answer with that, has to be "Lair of the White Worm".

Answer (score 4):

It sounds somewhat like **The Lair of the White Worm** (1988), starring Amanda Donohoe, Peter Capaldi, and Hugh Grant.

- [IMDB page for The Lair of the White Worm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095488/)
- [Wikipedia entry for The Lair of the White Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lair_of_the_White_Worm_(film))

Comment: I am yet to get a copy of this movie so that I can watch it and go back to my childhood. I will accept your answer after I really watch it. Perhaps my thank you may sound different then ;)

There is some resemblance which I need to justify to myself before saying - this is it!

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. Until you see it with your own eyes you won't know whether it fits the memories.

Comment: I watched "The Lair of the White Worm" movie yesterday but it felt as if I have never seen it before. I am sorry but I do not feel if this is the right one I am looking for, the search goes on...